# Javascript: Why using anonymous functions and return statements

Tags: javascript

The title isn't really describing what I'm looking for, so I can show it with example. 
What is the difference between this:

```
function Hotel(rooms, booked){
 this.rooms = rooms;
 this.booked = books;
 this.checkAvailability = function(){
  return this.rooms - this.booked;
 };
}
```

And this:

```
function Hotel(rooms, booked){
 this.rooms = rooms;
 this.booked = booked;
 this.checkAvailability = this.rooms - this.booked;
 };
}
```

In my second example, I didn't use the anonymous function and the return statement but it gives exactly the same result. Why is that? Or, which one is the "correct" one?

Comment: Initialization vs function call.

Comment: In the top option, `this.checkAvailability` is set as a immutable value-- it can be viewed with simple dot notation, and will never change, even if `this.rooms` or `this.booked` _do_ change.  In the below block, it is a function, that will return the value when called as `this.checkAvailability()` -- this way, if the value of `this.rooms` or `this.booked` update, you can get a fresh evaluation of availability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you're initializing and nothing else.  The state of `checkAvailability` will never change.

```js
function Hotel(rooms, booked){
 this.rooms = rooms;
 this.booked = booked;
 this.checkAvailability = this.rooms - this.booked;
}

var hotel = new Hotel(2, 1);
hotel.rooms = 1;
console.log(hotel.checkAvailability); // See?, regardless of assigning a new value, the result is 2 - 1 = 1
```

Here you're initializing with a function that will calculate the `checkAvailability`.

```js
function Hotel(rooms, booked){
 this.rooms = rooms;
 this.booked = booked;
 this.checkAvailability = function(){
  return this.rooms - this.booked;
 };
}

var hotel = new Hotel(2, 1);
hotel.rooms = 1;
console.log(hotel.checkAvailability()); // See?, now it was calculated with the new value, the result is 1 - 1 = 0
```

Comment: Lately, someone is downvoting to everyone!  And this is not the only question where this guy is doing that.

Answer (score -1):

None is considered "wrong" or "correct". They do different things.

- The top snippet creates a method that dynamically compute the value, while
- The bottom snippet pre-compute the value, i.e. `checkAvailability` will not be updated to match the value if `rooms` or `booked` is changed.

In normal cases however, you probably want to do this:

```
class Hotel {
    constructor(rooms, booked) {
        this.rooms = rooms;
        this.booked = books;
    }
    checkAvailability() {
        return this.rooms - this.booked;
    }
}
```

This avoids creating multiple copy of the same function.

Answer (score -1):

The first one would be the correct one.
The second example's checkAvailability only holds as long as rooms and booked don't change.

For example:

```js
function Hotel(rooms, booked){
 this.rooms = rooms;
 this.booked = booked;
 this.checkAvailability = function(){
  return this.rooms - this.booked;
 };
}

function NonUpdatingHotel(rooms, booked){
 this.rooms = rooms;
 this.booked = booked;
 this.checkAvailability = this.rooms - this.booked;
}

hotel = new Hotel(4, 3)
console.log(hotel.checkAvailability())
hotel.booked = 2
console.log(hotel.checkAvailability())

hotel = new NonUpdatingHotel(4, 3)
console.log(hotel.checkAvailability)
hotel.booked = 2
console.log(hotel.checkAvailability)
```